# replace line breaks in a json encoded string error?

Tags: php, string, json, line-breaks

I want to replace linebreaks with `' '` in PHP. Somehow I can't get it to work on this json encoded string  `[[0,"Hello World"],[1,"s\n"]]` with `$x = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n\r|\n/m', ' ', $x);`.

I'm out of ideas. And i know that the php code works with none-json encoded strings. Any ideas to fix this problem

Forgot this:

When I input the string as `$x`the function or php code returns the same string. Instead of replacing `\n` with `' '`.

I have also tried all relevant problems in Stackoverflow. none of them successful

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Provide "before" and "after" strings for clarity.

Comment: When I input the string as $xthe function or php code returns the same string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace will try to parse the '\n' as an actual newline character, so you need some more escaping in there.

```
$x = preg_replace('/\\\r\\\n|\\\r|\\\n\\\r|\\\n/m', ' ', $x);
```

This is all kind of ugly though. Is there a reason you can't do a replace in the actual decoded strings instead?

Comment: Thanks @Logan it worked! I dont want to replace in the client side though

Comment: I seriously doubt that that works and fixes your problem. I tried the pattern from your question, and that works; this escaped one (though escaping isn't necessary since the pattern is between single quotes which does nothing with \n or \r) doesn't work.

Comment: I'll be honest, I kind of expected his sample code to work too, but when I tried it on my computer, it didn't. I tried it with the extra escaping and it works. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and PHP 5.3.3, you?

Comment: @Logan I've tested on the same system.